# Inject a specific subset of all existing Datasources

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

I need to be able to deal with a dynamic list of Datasources.
To do that i wrote a `@Bean` method that returns a map of datasources.

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "partitioning.shards")
public Map<String, DataSource> datasources() {
    Map<String, DataSource> datasources = new HashMap<>();
    ...
    return datasources;
}
```

i a second step i need to process these datasources in a different class. unfortunately i have another factory-method that also creates Datasources to a different database.

is it possible to only get the Datasources injected that my own method created? i tried to annotate my method with a qualifier but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was wrong on multiple fronts:

returning a map of datasources does not add the datasources to my context. it just looked like that because of something else my code did. after adding my beans with seperate @Bean methods the Qualifier annotation worked aggain without a problem.